# « Association » majuscule ou minuscule

Tags: grammaire

Lorsqu'on écrit seulement « association » (l'association/l'Association, cette association/cette Association) pour indiquer l'Association de la jeunesse auxerroise qu'on a déjà mentionnée avant, le mot prend-il une majuscule ou une minuscule ?

Comment: Voir [compagnie, société, entreprise, etc.](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_c&page=9wIj12fz4tm8.html) qui indique que, dans une dénomination sociale, la règle générale est d’écrire les mots tels que compagnie, société et entreprise (ou association) avec une majuscule s’ils font partie intégrante du nom officiel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lorsqu'on parle d'une institution, le mot "Association" prend une majuscule :

- *L'**A**ssociation sportive de Paris*
- *L'**A**ssociation étudiante de Tourcoing*

Mais si c'est simplement le nom commun désignant un ensemble, c'est une minuscule :

- *L'**a**ssociation des mots forme une phrase.*
- *L'**a**ssociation des ingrédients donne un gâteau.*

Donc dans le cas mentionné, on dirait l'**Association de la jeunesse auxerroise**. Puis on **rementionnera l'organisme avec une majuscule**, si ce n'est un acronyme : AJA, AJ Auxerre dans ce cas.

---

De la même manière avec d'autres mots :

- *La Fondation Pierre et Marie Curie* / *Les fondations de la maison s'écroulent.*
- *Le Cercle des Sportifs de Vincennes* / *Je trace un cercle.*
- *L'Orchestre symphonique de Montréal* / *Je joue dans un orchestre.*
- *L'Eglise a élu un nouveau pape.* / *Je vais à la messe à l'église du village.*

Comment: ça ne répond pas à la question, car dans l'exemple cité, le mot association est utilisé pour la même chose, mais dans des contexte différents. *"J'ai rejoint l'Association X cette année. Cette association/Association œuvre pour [...]"*. Le mot désigne  toujours une institution, mais ce serait bizarre de toujours l'écrire avec une majuscule.

Comment: En effet @TeleportingGoat : j'ai précisé ma réponse, merci :)
Vu qu'on mentionne un organisme, on laisse la majuscule, même si on enlève la particule "jeunesse auxerroise", car l'Association reste une institution.

Comment: The OP asked about its behavior in English as well; *association* behaves the same way in English—it's capitalized if it stands for a particular organization, but it's lowercase if it's talking about associations in general.

Comment: @PeterShor yes but I do not know the english language well enough to be able to answer this part of the question, thank you though

Comment: @Marck: No need for you to answer that part of the question; this is the wrong site for that. And it's already been answered on [English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/319930/if-there-is-a-constant-reference-to-a-particular-fire-department-is-fire-depar/353318#353318).